# How to Sort ListView Columns (Data from SQL Table)

Tags: sql, vb.net, listview, sorting

How do you go about sorting data by clicking on the column header when your data is retrieved from a database table?

Is there an easy way of doing it or do I need to respond on the header's "click" event to call an "ORDER BY" on my query?

Comment: Which kind of datasource is binded to your datagridview? (DataView, List<T> or...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by following this link:

- [How to: Sort ListView Items (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229643%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

On step three, I didn't manually add my items but it still worked.